# Neo4j cql behaves different in Windows and Linux

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-cql

I have created following relation in Nodejs.

```
CREATE (s1:service {name:'service A'})
CREATE (s2:service {name:'service B'})
CREATE (s3:service {name:'service C'})

MATCH (s1:service {name:'service A'}),(s2:service {name:'service B'}),(s3:service {name:'service C'})
MERGE (s1)-[:calls]->(s2)
MERGE (s1)-[:invokes]->(s3)
MERGE (s2)-[:calls]->(s3)
```

And when I run following cql in Windows, I get the graph like below which is expected.

```
MATCH p=(:service)-[:calls]->(:service)-[:calls]->(:service) return p
```

[image]

And for the same cql query, neo4j in linux returns different graph, in which the "invokes" relation is not expected.

[image]

I couldn't find much help from the documentation relevant to this. Can someone help on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may just be due to a difference in the neo4j Browser settings used to view the results of the 2 queries.

When "autocomplete" mode is on, the neo4j Browser will show all relationships between returned nodes -- even relationships that your Cypher query did not return. (If you view the Text result instead of the Graph result, you should see your expected results.)

To check if that setting is on, enter this command in the neo4j Browser you use for linux:

```
:config
```

If the returned map contains `"autoComplete": true`, you can turn off that setting by entering this command:

```
:config autoComplete:false
```

After turning off "autocomplete" mode, re-perform the query. The Graph visualization should no longer show extra relationships.

Comment: Oh yeah. This resolved the problem. This is some minor config unnoticed since I had my windows configured a while ago.